# Regex: Remove Certain Parameter and Value From URL

Tags: php, regex

How do I remove certain parameter and its value from url?

```
<?php $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>
```

My urls can be `pagename?page=2` or `pagename?param=235235&page=2` or `pagename?page=10&param=5431` or etc.

I need remove `page=x` from url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach using php's built-in url functions without regex. More elegant IMHO

```
function removeParamFromURL($param, $url) {
    $parsed_url = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($parsed_url["query"], $querystringarray);
    unset($querystringarray[$param]);
    $parsed_url["query"] = http_build_query($querystringarray);
    return $parsed_url["scheme"] . "://" . $parsed_url["host"] . $parsed_url["path"] . "?" . $parsed_url["query"];
}
$url = "http://example.com/aaa/bbb/pagename/page.php?param=235235&page=2";
print $finalurl = removeParamFromURL("page", $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

> You have stated in your question that you wish to REMOVE page=xx from
>   the URL.

There's Nothing like the smell of regex in the afternoon... So I had a stab at this and the following should do the trick.

I'm sure it can be done more smartly, but it gets you up and running.

```
<?php
/*
 * My urls can be
 * pagename?page=2 or
 * pagename?param=235235&page=2 or
 * pagename?page=10&param=5431 or etc.
 */
function remove_page_from_url($url){
    // For the case where ?page=xx&param
    if (preg_match('/\?page=[0-9]{0,}&/',$url)){
        $url =  preg_replace('/&/','?',$url,1); // Only replace the 1st one.
    }
    return preg_replace('/[\?|&]page=[0-9]{0,}/','',$url);
}

// The Testing during development

//Case 1: This works
$url = 'pagename?page=10';
echo remove_page_from_url($url);
echo '<br>';

//Case 2: This works
$url = 'pagename?param=235235&page=2';
echo remove_page_from_url($url);
echo '<br>';

//Case 3: This works
//This messes things up as we also have to change a & to a ?
$url = 'pagename?page=10&param=5431';
echo remove_page_from_url($url);
echo '<br>';

//Case 4: This Works
//This messes things up as we also have to change a & to a ? but only the first one.
$url = 'pagename?page=10&param=5431&something=2';
echo remove_page_from_url($url);
echo '<br>';
```

So you start from the simplest case and work your way up.

```
/*
The Results

pagename?page=10
=>   pagename

pagename?param=235235&page=2
=>   pagename?param=235235

pagename?page=10&param=5431
=>   pagename?param=5431

pagename?page=10&param=5431&something=2
=>   pagename?param=5431&something=2
*/
```

So it is the code inside function `remove_page_from_url($url)` that you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

```
Remove dynamic parameters from a URL

 <?php
function remove_url_parmeter($url,$parameter_key){
        if($parameter_key && $url){
            foreach($parameter_key as $val){
                 if (preg_match('/[\?|&]'.$val.'=[0-9]{0,}/',$url)){
                    $url =  preg_replace('/&/','?',$url,1);
                 }
                 $url = preg_replace('/[\?|&]'.$val.'=[0-9]{0,}/','',$url);
            }
        }else{
            $url = 'This is not work';
        }
    return $url;

}

$url = "http://example.com/pagename?page=5&param=5431&page1=10&somepage=3";
//$parameter_key =array('page','page1');
echo remove_url_parmeter($url,array('page','page1'));

?>
```